# Error no photo data when uploading a photo from react js to mongodb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, post, get

When i upload an image to my website it sends the image to the backend to upload the image to mongodb database, I upload the base64 of the image to the database but the problem is that sometime the photo data will be "false " when i fetch the images back.
for example :

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0
: 
photo
: 
"false"
__v
: 
0
_id
: 
"650ce3fb077e8bd7795561e0"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
1
: 
photo
: 
"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAA
__v
: 
0
_id
: 
"650ce411077e8bd7795561e4"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
2
: 
photo
: 
"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAA
__v
: 
0
_id
: 
"650ce413077e8bd7795561e6"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
length
: 
3
```

Here the first photo data is " false " and nothing shows when it's fetched but the other two has data.
Also when i try to upload it again it sometimes normally works.
This is the "uploadImage" Code :

```
import express from 'express';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import Image from '../mongodb/models/image.js';
dotenv.config();

const router = express.Router();

router.route('/').get(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await Image.find({}).then( data => {
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: data });

    });
   
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Fetching posts failed, please try again' });
  }
});

router.route('/').post(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {base64} = req.body;
    await Image.create({
      photo: base64,
    });
    res.status(200).json({ success: true});
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Unable to upload the image, please try again' });
  }
});


export default router;
```

Upload Image Code in react :

```
  const handleImageUpload = async (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    reader.onload =() => {
      // base 64
      // console.log(reader.result)
      SetImage(reader.result)
    }
    reader.onerror = e  => {
      console.log("Reader Error " , e)
    }
   
    if (file) {
        const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      setForm({ ...form, file, photo: imageUrl });
        try {
      
        
          const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/uploadImage', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              Accept : "application/json",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              base64 : image
            }),
          });
          console.log(response);
          if (response.ok) {
            console.log('Image uploaded and saved successfully!');
          } else {
            console.error('Failed to upload image');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error uploading image:', error);
        }
      };
    }
```

Comment: _`base64 : image`_  where is `image` defined?

Comment: i save it in a state   const [image,SetImage] = useState(false)
and as you can see in   const file = e.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    reader.onload =() => {
      // base 64
      // console.log(reader.result)
      SetImage(reader.result)
    }
    reader.onerror = e  => {
      console.log("Reader Error " , e)
    }
   
    if (file) {
        const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      setForm({ ...form, file, photo: imageUrl });  i update the state with the image value when a user uploads one

Comment: At a quick glance, it just appears that at some point you sent empty data and an `Image` record was persisted with a false `photo` field

Comment: I will try to upload the images to a cloud service and store the url in the database instead .. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

So i found a weird solution for the problem
The problem was in this line of code : ` const base64Data = await readFileAsync(file);

```
  SetImage(base64Data);`
```

Sometimes the image base64 won't be saved in the "image" state even though that the condition was true.
So I Sent the base64 directly to the api like this :

```
if (file) {
    const imageUrl =   URL.createObjectURL(file);
  setForm({ ...form, file, photo: imageUrl });
    try {
      const base64Data = await readFileAsync(file);

    
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/uploadImage', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept : "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          base64 : base64Data
        }),
      });
```

and it worked.